# Calculating a conditional cumulative sum in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

The broad view of what I'm trying to do is find out how many reservations that have not yet happened yet are on the books in the entire system, by the date that the reservation was booked. This means counting the number of all records that exist with a `redemption_date` after or equal to `booking_date`, grouping by `booking_date`. Please see the following hypothetical example for a better explanation:

```
redemption_date      booking_date
2013-01-01           2013-01-01
2013-01-06           2013-01-01
2013-01-06           2013-01-01
2013-01-07           2013-01-02
2013-01-08           2013-01-03
2013-01-09           2013-01-04
2013-01-10           2013-01-05
2013-01-10           2013-01-05
2013-01-10           2013-01-05
2013-01-10           2013-01-05
2013-01-10           2013-01-05
2013-01-11           2013-01-05
```

I would like the result:

```
booking_date         number_of_reservations
2013-01-01           3
2013-01-02           3
2013-01-03           4
2013-01-04           5
2013-01-05           11
```

But my brain is completely failing me as to how the query should be structured. Any tips? Thanks!

Edit:
To clarify, number_of_reservations should be the number of reservations that were booked on that date, as well as those booked on days AFTER that. In other words, number_of_reservations is the number of reservations that are in the database as of booking_date (that have not yet happened).
My original results did have mistakes. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Is the desired result you are showing correct based on the sample data that you provided?

Comment: You are correct - my result was flawed. Thanks for pointing it out, hopefully the correction will make my question clearer.

Comment: did you check the internet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT
    booking_date,
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN redemption_date >= booking_date 
        THEN 1 END
    ) AS number_of_reservations
FROM
    Reservations
GROUP BY
    booking_date
```

### [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e755a/5)

---

### Edit:

Based on the updated description, I believe this should give the desired results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r."booking_date",
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM reservations r2 
     WHERE 
         r2."booking_date" <= r."booking_date"
         AND r2."redemption_date" >= r."booking_date"
    ) AS number_of_reservations
FROM
    Reservations r
ORDER BY r."booking_date"
```

### [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e755a/20)

Comment: wouldn't this count every record because it's using a COUNT?

Comment: Why not use a where clause? That should be more efficient.

Comment: @MattBusche Good question... no, because when the `CASE` statement doesn't match, it returns `NULL`, which isn't included in the count.

Comment: @HassanVoyeau Maybe... but that would exclude any bookings with a count of 0.

Comment: This does give the number of reservations made on each date, but that's not what I'm looking for. I need the number of reservations made UP TO each booking date that have not yet happened (where redemption_date > booking_date). So, a cumulative sum of reservations made up to each booking_date that have not happened yet. I've revised my original question a bit. Hopefully these clarifications make sense.

Comment: @TheInternet What about the second query?  The results in the fiddle seem to match with the requested results...

Answer (score 4):

You can do this readily by using `case` with a `sum`.

```
select booking_date,
       SUM(case when redemption_date >= booking_date then 1 else 0 end)
from bookings b
group by booking_date
order by booking_date
```

By the way, this isn't really a cumulative sum.  The would have the syntax:

```
sum(whatever) over (partition by . . . order by . . . )
```

It would put a calculated value on every row.

Comment: @svlada . . . If you have a question, then ask it as a question.

Answer (score 2):

this should get you what you're looking for

```
SELECT booking_date, SUM(CASE WHEN booking_date >= redemption_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_reservations
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY booking_date
ORDER BY booking_date
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (I am assuming that you want all of them, not ones that appear more than a certain number)

```
select booking_date, count(*) as number_of_reservations
from table_name
group by booking_date order by booking_date
```

Comment: he wants records where the `booking_date` is before or equal to the `redemption_date`

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple solution.

```
select a.trans_id,
  a.quantity+nvl((select sum(quantity) from table1 where trans_id<a.trans_id),0) quantity 
from table1 a 
order by a.sys_trans_id
```