# WITH Clause: Only including certain values from each table

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I'm attempting to write a query that will get the count of locations for a specific SKU  in each "location zone" and then a total count of all locations for consolidation purposes.

This is the code im using to attempt this:

```
WITH 
    C0R_Count AS (
        SELECT sku_id, count(location_id) as Bulk_Count
        FROM Inventory
        where location_id like 'C0R%'
        group by sku_id),
    C0S_Count AS (
        SELECT sku_id, count(location_id) as Bin_Count
        FROM Inventory
        where location_id like 'C0S%'
        group by sku_id)
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Bin_Count+Bulk_Count DESC)as Count_Rank,
        Inventory.sku_id, Bin_Count, Bulk_Count, 
        (Bin_Count+Bulk_Count) as Total_Count
FROM Inventory, C0R_Count, C0S_Count
WHERE client_id = 'SDRY-US' 
   and site_id = 'USCOL1' 
   and Inventory.Sku_id = C0R_Count.Sku_id 
   and Inventory.Sku_id = C0S_Count.Sku_id 
   and (Bin_Count+Bulk_Count) > 9
GROUP BY Inventory.sku_id, Bin_Count, Bulk_Count
;
```

Whats happening is the result is only including SKU's that have at least one location for both *Bulk_Count* and *Bin_Count*.

For example there is a specific SKU that shows up in 223 (Bin Count) locations  but doesn't show up in Bulk_Count locations. These are the top results shown using the current query but the SKU with a total count of 223 would have Rank 1 but its being excluded as the Bulk Count would be 0

```
COUNT_RANK  SKU_ID            BIN_COUNT  BULK_COUNT   TOTAL_COUNT
1           M10003NS-02A-.M    71        2                73
2           M10003NS-02A-.S    68        2                70
3           M10003NS-02A-.L    60        4                64
4           M10003NS-02A-.XL   61        2                63
```

Added the following using explicit join notation and received the same results.

```
WITH 
    C0R_Count AS (
        SELECT /*+ materialize */ 
        sku_id, count(location_id) as Bulk_Count
        FROM Inventory
        where location_id like 'C0R%'
        group by sku_id),
    C0S_Count AS (
        SELECT /*+ materialize */ 
        sku_id, count(location_id) as Bin_Count
        FROM Inventory
        where location_id like 'C0S%'
        group by sku_id)
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Bin_Count+Bulk_Count DESC)as Count_Rank,
       Inventory.sku_id, Bin_Count, Bulk_Count, 
       (Bin_Count+Bulk_Count) as Total_Count
FROM Inventory
Left Join C0R_Count
   on Inventory.Sku_id = C0R_Count.Sku_id
Left Join C0S_Count
   on Inventory.Sku_id = C0S_Count.Sku_id
WHERE 
   client_id = 'SDRY-US' 
   and site_id = 'USCOL1' 
   and (Bin_Count+Bulk_Count) > 9
GROUP BY Inventory.sku_id, Bin_Count, Bulk_Count
;
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the "WITH".  You need to use left joins you are only using inner joins.  To use left joins you should use new style join syntax

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh - no "if" here.   It is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems much more complicated than needed.  You can do all this with conditional aggregation and no subqueries or CTEs:

```
select rank() over (order by sum(case when location_id like 'C0R%' or location_id like 'C0s%' then 1 else 0 end) desc) as count_rank,
       sku_id,
       sum(case when location_id like 'C0R%' then 1 else 0 end) as Bulk_Count
       sum(case when location_id like 'C0S%' then 1 else 0 end) as Bin_Count
from Inventory i
where client_id = 'SDRY-US' and site_id = 'USCOL1' 
group by sku_id
having sum(case when location_id like 'C0R%' or location_id like 'C0s%' then 1 else 0 end) > 9;
```

You could introduce a subquery just to simplify the column aliases:

```
select rank() over (order by Bulk_Count + Bin_Count desc) as count_rank,
       i.*
from (select sku_id,
             sum(case when location_id like 'C0R%' then 1 else 0 end) as Bulk_Count
             sum(case when location_id like 'C0S%' then 1 else 0 end) as Bin_Count
      from Inventory i
      where client_id = 'SDRY-US' and site_id = 'USCOL1' 
      group by sku_id
     ) i
where Bulk_Count + Bin_Count > 9
```

Comment: Marking as the answer as the second query provided did as i was intending. Can you explain what the "then 1 else 0" statement is doing?

Comment: @arrchar . . . It is counting the number of rows that meet the condition.  I prefer `sum()` in this case instead of `count()`.

Comment: Disregard found the answer to my own question through another post you commented on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336422/how-sum-with-case-conditional-statement-works-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and post this as an answer – you *need* to use `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` syntax here.  The DBMS will logically interpret your existing SQL to implicitly mean `INNER` joins.

Also, you might need to reconsider your `GROUP BY` clauses.

You might need to use *subqueries* – first selecting the rows-of-interest, then summarizing this.

Comment: Is this a case of the `WITH` clause just not being useful? Are you recommending I just turn this into a series of subqueries?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WITH 
    C0R_Count AS (
        SELECT /*+ materialize */ 
        sku_id, count(location_id) as Bulk_Count
        FROM Inventory
        where location_id like 'C0R%'
        group by sku_id),
    C0S_Count AS (
        SELECT /*+ materialize */ 
        sku_id, count(location_id) as Bin_Count
        FROM Inventory
        where location_id like 'C0S%'
        group by sku_id)
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY nvl(Bin_Count,0)+nvl(Bulk_Count,0) DESC)as Count_Rank,
       Inventory.sku_id, Bin_Count, Bulk_Count, 
       (nvl(Bin_Count,0)+nvl(Bulk_Count,0)) as Total_Count
FROM Inventory
Left Join C0R_Count
   on Inventory.Sku_id = C0R_Count.Sku_id
Left Join C0S_Count
   on Inventory.Sku_id = C0S_Count.Sku_id
WHERE 
   client_id = 'SDRY-US' 
   and site_id = 'USCOL1' 
   and (nvl(Bin_Count,0)+nvl(Bulk_Count,0)) > 9
GROUP BY Inventory.sku_id, Bin_Count, Bulk_Count
;
```

When null values are calculated, they become null values.

Comment: Nice catch, hadn't thought about the query being unable to calculate or display the null values. Provided query gets the desired results but includes the null values doesn't change them to 0's