# Counts not providing a totaled value

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have some code set up to (hopefully) monitor how many fly-tips we had in the current month based on the fly-tip location, and how many fly-tips we had for the previous month.

The syntax is accepted by the system however it isn't bringing back any values - just 0.

I'm new to Oracle SQL and think I need to link the sub-query to the main query but not sure how

What I want to achieve is a table that says:

```
Location Type            Current Month             Last Month
Back Alley                    132                      203
Rail Land                       4                       23
```

The code I have is:

```
  select        parameter_value.param_value_name as Fly_tip_location,

(select count (parameter_value.param_value_name) from   job
inner join  job_attribute on job.job_number = job_attribute.job_number
inner join  parameter_value on parameter_value.param_type_code = job_attribute.param_type_code and
            parameter_value.param_value_code = job_attribute.param_value_code
inner join job_status_log on job.job_number = job_status_log.job_number and job.job_log_number = job_status_log.job_log_number
inner join job_status on job_status.status_code = job_status_log.status_code
where       job_attribute.param_type_code = 'FT02' and
job_status.status_code = '5200' and
 job.actual_start_date >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MM')
  AND job.actual_start_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')) as Last_Month_Total,

(select count (parameter_value.param_value_name) from   job
inner join  job_attribute on job.job_number = job_attribute.job_number
inner join  parameter_value on parameter_value.param_type_code = job_attribute.param_type_code and
            parameter_value.param_value_code = job_attribute.param_value_code
inner join job_status_log on job.job_number = job_status_log.job_number and job.job_log_number = job_status_log.job_log_number
inner join job_status on job_status.status_code = job_status_log.status_code
where       job_attribute.param_type_code = 'FT02' and
job_status.status_code = '5200' and
 job.actual_start_date >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 0), 'MM')
  AND job.actual_start_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')) as Current_Month_Total

 from job
inner join  job_attribute on job.job_number = job_attribute.job_number
inner join  parameter_value on parameter_value.param_type_code = job_attribute.param_type_code and
            parameter_value.param_value_code = job_attribute.param_value_code
inner join job_status_log on job.job_number = job_status_log.job_number and job.job_log_number = job_status_log.job_log_number
inner join job_status on job_status.status_code = job_status_log.status_code


group by    parameter_value.param_value_name
order by    parameter_value.param_value_name`
```

Comment: I suggest a straight-forward query with ***conditional aggregation***.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336422/how-sum-with-case-conditional-statement-works-in-sql

Comment: Completely agree with simplifying; but with what you have now, do you get zero for both counts, or only for current month? (Look at the date range that second subquery is searching for - it can never find anything). Also not sure why you join all the tables again in the outer query - shouldn't that just be against `parameter_value`? I'd also think about introducing table aliases to make it a bit easier to read.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of that perhaps??

Comment: I get zero for both counts.
I've only been doing SQL for about 2 months so still REALLY new to coding conventions but essentially I've pulled 2 count queries that I know work on their own together, thinking that they might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see why you might get a zero count for the current month value; your second subquery has:

```
job.actual_start_date >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 0), 'MM')
AND job.actual_start_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'))
```

which is the same as

```
job.actual_start_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
AND job.actual_start_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'))
```

and a column value can't be both `>=` *and* `<` the same value.

I'm not sure why you'd get zero counts for the previous month too - without correlation I'd expect that to be higher than you want maybe, but not zero, so maybe there's something in the data we can't see.

Anyway... as @PM77-1 suggested you can simplify this with conditional aggregation, something like:

```
select pv.param_value_name as fly_tip_location,
  count(case when j.actual_start_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'MM') then j.job_number end) as current_month,
  count(case when j.actual_start_date < trunc(sysdate, 'MM') then j.job_number end) as last_month
from job j
join job_status_log jsl on jsl.job_number = j.job_number
and jsl.job_log_number = j.job_log_number
--join job_status js on js.status_code = jsl.status_code -- not needed
join job_attribute ja on ja.job_number = j.job_number
join parameter_value pv on pv.param_type_code = ja.param_type_code
and pv.param_value_code = ja.param_value_code
where j.actual_start_date >= trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM')
and jsl.status_code = '5200'
and pv.param_type_code = 'FT02'
group by pv.param_value_name
order by pv.param_value_name;
```

This hits all the tables once - you don't need `job_status` so I've commented that out, but it can be removed completely - and filters on the overall date range as anything after the start of the previous month, and the status code and parameter type you're interested in.

Then in each of the aggregation/count clauses, it's using a case expression to decide which month's data it is counting. In the first one it only counts jobs whose start dates are after the start of the current month; in the second one it only counts jobs whose start dates are before the start of the current month - i.e. in the previous month, as that's all that is left from the filter in the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks for that.
When I've put it into the system it is bringing back an error message


"Select error: SQLSTATE = 22005
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722: invalid number"

Comment: @RobMorris - OK, I guess I assumed status code was a number but perhaps it isn't; can you change `5200` back to `'5200'` and see if that clears it?

Comment: Fantastic!!
That's sorted it and brought all the information through.
Thank you so much for your help on this and for taking the time to explain it clearly!