# Unable to sum DEMAND in SQL for each Item across Transaction Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create an inventory report from an Oracle database that requires a join on two tables, and to create a calculated column for DEMAND using a CASE statement, since the value for DEMAND depends on the value of the SOURCE column.

Below is the SQL I have written, which executes without error. However, I need a sum of DEMAND across transaction dates (TRAN_DATE), and I am unsure how to do this. Can someone please help with this?

I have also included sample output. For the 090CAP ITEMNO, the demand is OUT_QTY since the value of SOURCE is REQUIRED. However, I want the demand to be the sum of the two demands per TRAN_DATE (i.e. 29,787.1410 + 11,012.8590 = 40,800), and ultimately I do not want to display TRAN_DATE in my results.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT  
    ARINVT.ITEMNO, 
    ARINVT.REV, 
    ARINVT.DESCRIP, 
    ARINVT.ONHAND, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.OUT_QTY, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SHIP_QUAN, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SHIP_QUAN_NATIVE, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SOURCE, 
    (CASE 
    WHEN V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SOURCE = 'BACKLOG'  
    THEN V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SHIP_QUAN_NATIVE  
    WHEN V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SOURCE = 'REQUIRED'  
    THEN  V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.OUT_QTY  
    ELSE 0 
    END) AS "DEMAND", 
    ARINVT.PK_HIDE AS "PK_HIDE", 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.TRAN_DATE
FROM 
    (((ARINVT LEFT JOIN IQMS.V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX ON (ARINVT."ID" = V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX."ARINVT_ID")) 
        LEFT JOIN IQMS.EPLANT ON (ARINVT."EPLANT_ID" = EPLANT."ID")) )
WHERE 
    ( ((ARINVT.PK_HIDE IS NULL) ) 
        OR ((ARINVT.PK_HIDE =' ') )
        OR ((ARINVT.PK_HIDE ='N') ) ) 
ORDER BY 
    ARINVT.CLASS, 
    ARINVT.ITEMNO
```

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRQZW.png)

Comment: `sum()` around your `case` expression, `group by` everything else? By the way, none of the brackets are needed.

Comment: Thank you, William. I have given it a try and I get the following error:  ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 0):

A [`CASE` statement can go inside a `SUM` aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29336613/7359502).

```
SELECT  
    ARINVT.ITEMNO, 
    ARINVT.REV, 
    ARINVT.DESCRIP, 
    ARINVT.ONHAND, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.OUT_QTY, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SHIP_QUAN, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SHIP_QUAN_NATIVE, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SOURCE, 
    sum(
      CASE 
        WHEN V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SOURCE = 'BACKLOG'  
          THEN V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SHIP_QUAN_NATIVE  
        WHEN V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SOURCE = 'REQUIRED'  
          THEN  V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.OUT_QTY  
        ELSE 0 
      END
    ) AS "DEMAND", 
    ARINVT.PK_HIDE AS "PK_HIDE"
FROM 
    ARINVT 
    LEFT JOIN IQMS.V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX 
       ON ARINVT."ID" = V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX."ARINVT_ID" 
    LEFT JOIN IQMS.EPLANT 
       ON ARINVT."EPLANT_ID" = EPLANT."ID"
WHERE 
    ARINVT.PK_HIDE IS NULL 
 OR ARINVT.PK_HIDE IN (' ', 'N')
GROUP BY 
    ARINVT.ITEMNO, 
    ARINVT.REV, 
    ARINVT.DESCRIP, 
    ARINVT.ONHAND, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.OUT_QTY, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SHIP_QUAN, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SHIP_QUAN_NATIVE, 
    V_ARINVT_AVAIL_PROJECT_DTL_EX.SOURCE, 
    ARINVT.PK_HIDE
ORDER BY 
    ARINVT.CLASS, 
    ARINVT.ITEMNO
```